# Is there a way to create a ListBox or ListView with separate columns

Tags: c#, xaml

Is there a way to make a ListView in XAML that displays columns separately. for instance i have a name, and want to put an update and delete icon in the other columns. like this:

|name     |update(pic)  |delete(pic)   |

I have tried using a gridview inside the listview but that just displays all columns in one "line" like this:

|name      update(pic)   delete(pic)|

so they are not separated.

i have also tried putting a listview inside another lisview. one being oriented vertical and the other horizonzal to create this Grid effect. with nu luck.

here is my XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="grouplist" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Grouplist, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="grouplist_Selected" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="138" Grid.RowSpan="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,2,0,0" Grid.Row="3">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="3">
                        <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/Main;component/Resources/Images/update.png" Width="40" Height="40"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="4">
                        <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/Main;component/Resources/Images/delete.png" Width="40" Height="40"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

Here is my ViewModel that has the GroupList property. This bit works fine but ill just post it anyway. Just in case.

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _groupslist;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Grouplist
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupslist;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupslist = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GroupList"));
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the result i get. but i need the lists to be separate. not one Line.

[result of the lisview at runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIU3S.png)

i have tried everything i can think of but nothing seems to give me the result im aiming for. Any help is welcome! Thanks in advance.

Solution for the problem i had was using a DataGrid instead of a listView or ListBox:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grouplist" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Grouplist, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                          Height="138" Grid.RowSpan="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168" 
                          Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,2,0,0" Grid.Row="3"
                          SelectionMode="Single"
                          HeadersVisibility="None">

                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding}" Selector.Selected="grouplist_Selected"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/Main;component/Resources/Images/update.png" Width="40" Height="40"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/Main;component/Resources/Images/delete.png"  Width="40" Height="40"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. You can put a `DataGrid` inside `ListView` View. You'll achieve what you want. Separator Columns etc. You can customise the column data representation as per your choice. Text With Image, Text Without Image.

Internet is full of articles on this.

OR

In your current code, you can go for `SharedSizeGroup` where you can share sizes across multiple templates like this

```
<ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="FirstColumn"/>
<ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SecondColumn"/>
```

Comment: Yep, DaraGrid did the trick! but i used a new DataGrid. Not a datagrid in the Listview:

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I have added `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope = "True"` to the top Grid, and each column now has it's own size group. This will result in each column having the same width and hopefully line them up nicely.

```
<ListBox x:Name="grouplist" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Grouplist, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
 SelectionChanged="grouplist_Selected" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="138" Grid.RowSpan="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
 Width="168" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,2,0,0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" SharedSizeGroup="column1"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="column2"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="column3"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                        <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                        <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/Main;component/Resources/Images/update.png" Width="40" Height="40"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
                        <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/Main;component/Resources/Images/delete.png" Width="40" Height="40"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: they are now lined up indeed. but it still gives me one result column.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused because you keep saying ``ListView``, but your code contains a ``ListBox``. If you really need the separators then you need to put a ``GridView`` as your ``ListView.View``, and set up ``GridViewColumn``'s